# Why is ListViewGroup sealed?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

I can subclass ListViewItem and even ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem, but I can't subclass ListViewGroup.

Why is that?

Comment: Why would you derive from ListViewGroup. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The standard ListViewGroup does not support any of the new features of v6 common controls. A subclass would be the natural way to extend the functionality of the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no answer as Microsoft will answer "Its by Design", lot of classes are Sealed that makes development very difficult and in some cases, we used Reflector to understand how family of classes work and we recreated our own classes to extend functionality. One of them was to build validations and error templates, but yes there is no answer for such question except its by Design.

Answer (score 2):

ListViewGroup is sealed because there's no way you can add or change it's functionality. The implementation doesn't *live* in `ListViewGroup`.

ListViewGroup is a friendly wrapper around native Win32 control. You can't descend a new class hoping to add functionality - the functionality isn't in the class.

---

It's the same reason that `ImageList` is sealed. If an image list is assigned to a `ListView`, that image list **must** be a wrapper around the native ImageList control, that's just how the listview is. You can't descend from ImageList in order to support alpha-blended PNG image lists - it just won't work.

The classes are sealed when there is poor encapsulation, and there is no point in descending because there's nothing you can legitimately change.